# Using html5 to scroll forwards / backwards through textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

I'm moving from traditional client / server side scripting to try and embrace some of the new technologies to make the web act more like a desktop application.

I have a php script where people can paste the contents of a report into a textarea and then read through it line by line. At the moment the text is copied to the server and stored in a database - this means each time the user wants to move forward or back there is a call to a server and the screen is redrawn.

I want to make this quicker, look nicer and avoid the server if I possibly can. I've spent the evening searching online for a class or a guide to this sort of thing and come up blank. It may be because I am unfamiliar with the subject and am not searching on the right terms.

For background I'm confident with html4, php, mysql and css - learning html5 and just starting to look at jQuery. Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: needs more details, example code, or at least links to something like it.

Comment: Here are snippets of the relevant existing code, it is very old but hopefully will give you a feel for what I am trying to do.

//Display Main Details
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$ThisTurn=$row['TurnDetails'];

$nextlines=$lines+1;

$url="index.php?selection=42&GameID=$GameID&lines=$nextlines";
echo "<hr /><p><a href=\"$url\">Display Next Line</a></p>";

//Retrieve newest line and set header etc
.. 

//Loop through results and display last one only 
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$ThisLine=$row['LineDetails'];
}

echo "<h3>Newest line - </h3>";
echo "<p><em>$ThisLine</em></p>";

Answer (score 0):

**Not sure if this is what you are looking for**

```
<textarea wrap="off">
 </textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use CSS, here's something that might work:

```html
<textarea rows="15" columns="50" style="resize: none;"></textarea>
```